# How to add files but not subdirectories to args list using :arga in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

When using `:arga *` subdirectories are beging added to argument list.

I can use `:arga *.js` or `:arga *.*` but that will not include files such as `.gitignore` or `vimrc`.

Is there any way to do something like `:arga file *` to only include files but not directories?

Answer (score 1):

You can use backtick expression for that:

```
:args `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f`
```

If you want to sort that, remember that pipe characters does not work corretly in backtick expressions (they must be escaped), but expression can be written like that using systemlist()

```
:args `=systemlist("find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f \| sort")`
```

All this can be used to define mapping to f.ex. populate arguments list with alphabetically sorted files in current file directory.

```
nmap <Leader>a :cd %:p:h<CR>:args `=systemlist("find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f \| sort")`<CR>
```